# VBA - "Error 9: Subscript out of range" when using UsedRange.Rows.Count function on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro in VBA that enables me to enter a keyword in Column F that, upon saving, will cut/paste the row I'm editing over to a different sheet in the workbook.

In broad terms, WORKSHEET 1 is the main sheet I work in. In WORKSHEET 1, if I type "AG" into Column F and click Save, the row I'm editing should disappear from WORKSHEET 1 and appear instead at the bottom of WORKSHEET 2; using the keyword "CL" in Column F instead should send the row I'm editing to WORKSHEET 3.

This system has been working fine until today. Suddenly I've started getting the "subscript out of range" error message. When I go to debug, it points to the line that's flanked by *** in which I assign `H = Worksheets("Daily Email").UsedRange.Rows.Count`

```
Sub ArchiveThisRow()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim H As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    Dim L As Long
    ***H = Worksheets("Daily Email").UsedRange.Rows.Count***
    J = Worksheets("AG Mtg Archive").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    L = Worksheets("Client Mtg Archive").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("AG Mtg Archive").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    If L = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Client Mtg Archive").UsedRange) = 0 Then L = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Daily Email").Range("F6:F" & H)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "AG" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("AG Mtg Archive").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "AG" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "CL" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Client Mtg Archive").Range("A" & L + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "CL" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            L = L + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've tried renaming the variable and classing it as an Integer rather than a Long, but I still get the same error message every time.

Comment: Validate the first sheet's name with `?sheets(1).name` in the VBE immediate window

Comment: Have you checked if the worksheet was renamed? If it was, deal with it, e.g. use code names instead of names e.g. `Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count`, or previously change the code name to something more friendly e.g. `Daily_Email` (no spaces allowed). If it was not then you should qualify the worksheet (specify the workbook). If the code is in the workbook containing this worksheet, use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Email").UsedRange.Rows.Count`. Otherwise, use something like `Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Sheets("Daily Email").UsedRange.Rows.Count`.